# How to get the rotation of a camera in three.js scene currently?

Tags: three.js, camera, rotation

In this example " https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webxr#webxr_ar_paint "
I try to get the rotation of camera.
In every frame, I use the method below to get the rotation value currently.

```
// use "camera.rotation" to get the current value of rotation.
console.log(camera.rotation);
```

However, those log I got were always the same value below.

```
Vector3 {x:0, y:0, z:-1}
Vector3 {x:0, y:0, z:-1}
Vector3 {x:0, y:0, z:-1}
Vector3 {x:0, y:0, z:-1}
........
```

How can I solve the problem?

The version of three.js I used is r117

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the transform properties of a camera (`position`, `rotation` and `scale`) does currently not return correct values when presenting XR content. More details in this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18448

As a workaround try to get the rotation in world space like so:

```js
camera.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion );
```

Notice that the rotation is expressed as a quaternion. If you need euler angles, just convert it via [Euler.setFromQuaternion()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Euler.setFromQuaternion).

`three.js r117`